# Integral in relative and center of mass variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to compute the following integral where $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are integrated inside a sphere of radius $l$:

$$I = \int\ d^3xd^3y\frac{1}{|\vec{x} - \vec{y}|^2}$$

To do it, I perform the change of variables:

$$\vec{r} = \vec{x} - \vec{y}, \quad \vec{R} = \frac{\vec{x} + \vec{y}}{2}$$

This change is such that

$$d^3xd^3y = d^3rd^3R$$

So now we have:

$$I = \int\ dr\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi\int\ R^2dR\sin\theta' d\theta' d\varphi'$$

Where $\vec{r}$ has spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \varphi)$ and $\vec{R}$ has ($R, \theta', \varphi'$). My problem is that I do not know how to write the limits in this last integral. I've tried: $r \in (0, 2l), \theta \in (0, \pi/2), \varphi \in (0, 2\pi)$ and $R \in (0, l), \theta' \in (0, \pi), \varphi' \in (0, 2\pi)$ but these ones do not reproduce the original volume, i.e., $\int d^3xd^3y = (\frac{4\pi l^3}{3})^2$, so I'm really stuck.

---

**EDIT:** the solution label by the green check gives a solution for I without making use of this change of variable. If anyone is able to solve I with $\{\vec{r}, \vec{R}\}$, feel free giving a new answer. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: When the integrand is $\lvert x-y\rvert^{-1}$ the original integral can be evaluated with a simple application of divergence theorem.  With the inverse-square it is a much nastier problem. 
Anyhow, using center of mass and relative coordinates result in really nasty limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based only on the use of spherical coordinates:

For $\vec{x} \in B_R(0)$ we define
$$ J(\vec{x}) = \int \limits_{B_R(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 \vec{y}}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2} \, . $$
Then 
$$ I = \int \limits_{B_R(0)} \mathrm{d}^3 \vec{x} \,J(\vec{x}) \, .$$
We rotate the $\vec{y}$-coordinate system in such a way that $\vec{x}$ points in positive $y_3$-direction and introduce spherical coordinates to obtain
\begin{align}
J(\vec{x}) &= \int \limits_{B_R(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 \vec{y}}{|\vec{x}|^2 + |\vec{y}|^2 - 2 |\vec{x}| y_3} \\
&= \int \limits_0^R \mathrm{d} r \, r^2 \int \limits_{-1}^1 \mathrm{d} \cos(\theta) \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d} \phi \, \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^2 + r^2 - 2 |\vec{x}| r \cos(\theta)} \\
&= \frac{2 \pi}{|\vec{x}|} \int \limits_0^R \mathrm{d} r \, r \ln \left(\frac{r + |\vec{x}|}{|r-|\vec{x}||}\right)
\end{align}
for $\vec{x} \neq 0$ and $J(0) = 4 \pi R$ . The remaining integral for $\vec{x} \neq 0$ can be split into two parts ($r < |\vec{x}|$ and $r > |\vec{x}|$), which are readily computed via integration by parts. The final result is
\begin{align} J(\vec{x}) &= 2 \pi \left[R + \frac{(R+|\vec{x}|)(R-|\vec{x}|)}{2 |\vec{x}|} \ln \left(\frac{R + |\vec{x}|}{R-|\vec{x}|}\right)\right] \\
&= 2 \pi R \left[1+(1-|\vec{x}|^2 /R^2) \frac{\operatorname{artanh}(|\vec{x}|/R)}{|\vec{x}|/R}\right]
\end{align}
for $\vec{x} \in B_R (0) \setminus \{0\}$ .

Now we can evaluate $I$ (again using spherical coordinates and integration by parts):
\begin{align}
I &= 8 \pi^2 R \int \limits_0^R \mathrm{d} r \, r^2 \left[1+(1-r^2 /R^2) \frac{\operatorname{artanh}(r/R)}{r/R}\right] \\
&= 8 \pi^2 R^4 \int \limits_0^1 \mathrm{d} \rho \, \left[\rho^2 + \rho (1-\rho^2) \operatorname{artanh}(\rho)\right] \\
&= 8 \pi^2 R^4 \left[\frac{1}{3} + \int \limits_0^1  \mathrm{d} \rho \, \frac{1}{4} (1-\rho^2)^2 \frac{1}{1-\rho^2} \right] \\
&= 4 \pi^2 R^4 \, .
\end{align}

Similarly (but with less effort), we can compute
$$ \int \limits_{B_R(0) \times B_R(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 \vec{x} \mathrm{d}^3 \vec{y}}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|} = \frac{32}{15} \pi^2 R^5 \, . $$

Comment: Ok, really thanks for your effort. i'm goint to label this answer as the correct one but I'm going to edit the question in order to let it open to someone that could find the solution for the change of variable that I proposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you integrate over a sphere the distance $r = |x-y|$ can go from $0$ up to $2l$ but you have to consider the starting point $R$, which if it is already on the edge of the sphere then r can only be 0 so the limit for r can be: $r ∈ (0, 2(l-R)).$
So the formula becomes:
$$
I = \int_0^l R^2 (\int_0^{2(l-R)} dr) dR \int_0^\pi \sin(\theta) d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin(\theta ') d\theta ' \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi ' = \frac{8}{3} \pi^2 l^4
$$

But this is different from the previous answer that gives $4\pi^2 l^2$ ($l$ in OP's notation, $R$ in previous answer's notation)

Comment: Is this the general way to take the limits for these 2 variables if we do not have any other condition or have some restriction?